# case insensitive check in if loop using regex in shell

Tags: shell, if-statement, ksh, case-insensitive

I want to check the following condition, but it should be case insensitive.
if [ "SPP" == $1 ]
Is there anyway I can do it using regex.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
shopt -s nocasematch
```

For case insensitive matching in BASH.

Alternatively this should also work:

```
[[ "$1" == [sS][pP][pP] ]]
```

Comment: if [ "[sS][pP][pP]" == "$1" ]
then echo $1
else echo "hello"
fi

On running the above script by passing spp as parameter, I am not getting the desired output
./b.sh spp
hello

Comment: Did you try: `shopt -s nocasematch`?

Comment: Ok I made a change as quotes are not needed. Try: `[ [sS][pP][pP] == "$1" ]`

Comment: not sure but this is also not working: if [ [sS][pP][pP] == "$1" ]
then echo "true"
else echo "false"
fi

Comment: See update again and try: `[[ "$1" == [sS][pP][pP] ]] && date` to see whether date is printed or not.

Comment: [[ "$1" == [sS][pP][pP] ]] is working but the other way round is not.

Comment: What is problem in this check? Is this not case sensitive?

Comment: my question is why is [ [sS][pP][pP] == "$1" ] not working. Isnt it same as [[ "$1" == [sS][pP][pP] ]]. And thanks atleast I have a solution.

Comment: No both conditions are not same. Shell glob pattern works on right hand side only.

Comment: If it worked for you can you mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can also do the following:

```
#!/bin/bash
myParam=`echo "$1" | tr 'a-z' 'A-Z'`
if [ "SPP" == "$myParam" ]; then
    echo "Is the same"
else
    echo "It is not the same"
fi
```

This script will automatically converts user input to uppercase before making any string comparison. By doing so, you will not have to use regex for case insensitive string comparison.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Better late than never...

If that's ksh93, use the ~(i:...) case-insensitive globbing sub-pattern:

```
if [[ $1 == *~(i:spp)* ]]; then
  : matched.
fi
```

For ksh88 (also the ksh clones), use an intermediary variable typeset -u'd to force upper-case:

```
typeset -u tocheck=$1
if [[ $tocheck == *SPP* ]]; then
  : matched
fi
```